How to use primevue scoped to a component?
I would like to use some primevue components in an existing project without switching everything to use primevue.
Is there a solution to prevent applying the style globally (or at least only on a specific vue router route ?

It consistently uses p- prefixed classes, so there's  generally no harm in using a style globally. The only global ones ones are font styles, this is specific to a theme https://unpkg.com/browse/primevue@3.51.0/resources/themes/arya-blue/theme.css#L2 . This one has a reasonable font initial value that may not affect anything
